# How Could I add Jcomponent during runtime with Swing Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer, jcomponent

I have Problem with Making adding RandomText(with random size, font,x,y) to JFrame every seconds this is my Code

first one is JComponent which expects Randomly Made String to appear

```
public class RandomTextGenerator extends JComponent{
    private String str;
    private Random r;
    private Color c;
    private Font f;
    private int x; 
    private int y;
    Graphics g;
    public RandomTextGenerator(String s)
    {

        r = new Random();
        c = new Color(r.nextInt(255),r.nextInt(255),r.nextInt(255));
        f = new Font("random",Font.BOLD,r.nextInt(100));
        x = r.nextInt(100);
        y = r.nextInt(100)+100;
        //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        str = s;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(c);
        g.setFont(f);
        System.out.println(str);
        g.drawString(str, x, y);
    }
}
```

Another one is JFrame

```
public class TextFrame extends JFrame{
    public TextFrame() {
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Random Text Generator");
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        this.add(new RandomTextGenerator("AAAAAAAA"));
        this.add(new RandomTextGenerator("BBBBBBBBBB"));
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void addRandomText(RandomTextGenerator r)
    {
        this.add(r);
        this.add(new RandomTextGenerator("CCC"));
        System.out.println("Method called");
        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

above Code,

```
this.add(new RandomTextGenerator("AAAAAAAA"));
this.add(new RandomTextGenerator("BBBBBBBBBB"));
```

those ones Works well and display on Screen but problem is method addRandomText

```
this.add(r);
this.add(new RandomTextGenerator("CCC"));
```

those ones do not works at all.

my main method is here

```
public class tfmain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Your Message");
            String str = s.nextLine();
            TextFrame tf = new TextFrame();
            Timer t = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener(){

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    tf.addRandomText(new RandomTextGenerator(str));
                }

            });
            t.start();
        }
}
```

with this code Method Called is appear which means that Timer Actually works.

but why adding Jcomponent isn't working?? adding Jcomponent in AddRandomtext never works(paintComponent is not called too)

Please Give me some advice. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: `f = new Font("random",Font.BOLD,r.nextInt(100));`  What is it, exactly, that you think the value of `"random"` will do?  General tips: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) `Graphics g;` Don't try to cache a graphics ..

Comment: .. object, it will end in failure, tears & recriminations.  Instead use the graphics object provided, and paint to it when asked to.  4) `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {..` should be `@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    { super.paintComponent(g); ..` to get a) the value of compile time checking and b) The BG of the component to be drawn.

Comment: BTW - I strongly suspect that `RandomTextGenerator` should **not** `extends JComponent`.  If the idea is to put a several pieces of text in random positions within a GUI, I would have a single custom painted component (or a `BufferedImage`) and a `List` of `RandomText` objects (which would be able to draw themselves to a `Graphics` object when requested).  Once you have the graphics object of the container in `paintComponent(..)` or from the image, iterate the list and draw each `RandomText`.

Comment: thank you so much your comment helps me a lot. I'm just 2nd grade of University and this is my first time to learn java. so I didn't know how i should handle GUI object..